# How to connect Actions on Google to an adroid app passing parameters

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm really new to android and Actions on Google and I'm working on a final project for college that requires an integration between the Actions and the Android app I've created.

I've been able to create an app that retrieves info from Firebase and shows all pets available for adoption. Within the app, the user can filter the results by selecting nested spinners for category, size, and finally breed.

I've also created an action on Google Actions Console that will run a conversational action with the user based on the two intents I have in Dialogflow: LookingForPet intent and the follow-up intent selectBreed
The LookingForPet intent is going to ask the user for a specific category, such as a dog or cat, and ask for size. Based on the user's reply, the Dialogflow is going to run a fulfillment function to retrieve the breeds that match those parameters and display it to the user asking them to select one of the breeds. As soon as the user replies to that question, another fulfillment function runs to retrieve the results found, displaying basic info of the entries in the database that match the given parameters.

What I need to do now is to be able to make the Google Assistant open the app in a specific Activity and get the value of these parameters (category, size, and breed) from the conversational action and store them in variables within my app, so I can rebuild the results on the screen.

I've been researching for a while now but I can't get to properly understand how to make it happen. As far as I could understand I'll need some intent-filters in my Manifest file within the specific activity I want to run, but I'm not really sure how to do that. Could any of you guys help me out?

Here is what I have on the Manifest file for the activity I want to launch:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResult">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="pawdopter.myapp.com"
            android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SELECT_CATEGORY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SELECT_SIZE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SELECT_BREED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is my actions.xml file, but I'm really confused about the fulfillment and parameter-mapping parts in here:

```
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
            urlTemplate="https://pawdopter.myapp.com/open{?searchresult}">
            <parameter-mapping intentParameter="search" urlParameter="searchresult"/>
        </fulfillment>
    </action>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.SELECT_CATEGORY">
        <parameter name="category.name">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="CategoryEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="intent:#Intent;package=com.myapp.pawdopter;action=com.myapp.pawdopter.SELECT_CATEGORY{;S.category};end">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="category.name"
                urlParameter="S.category"/>
        </fulfillment>
    </action>

    <action intentName="actions.intent.SELECT_SIZE">
        <parameter name="size.name">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="SizeEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="intent:#Intent;package=com.myapp.pawdopter;action=com.myapp.pawdopter.SELECT_SIZE{;S.size};end">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="size.name"
                urlParameter="S.size"/>
        </fulfillment>
    </action>

    <action intentName="actions.intent.SELECT_BREED">
        <parameter name="breed">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="BreedEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="intent:#Intent;package=com.myapp.pawdopter;action=com.myapp.pawdopter.SELECT_BREED{;S.breed};end">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="breed.name"
                urlParameter="S.breed"/>
        </fulfillment>
    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="CategoryEntitySet">
        <entity
            name="@string/category_dog"
            identifier="DOG"/>
        <entity
            name="@string/category_cat"
            identifier="CAT"/>
    </entity-set>

    <entity-set entitySetId="SizeEntitySet">
        <entity
            name="@string/size_small"
            identifier="SMALL"/>
        <entity
            name="@string/size_medium"
            identifier="MEDIUM"/>
        <entity
            name="@string/size_large"
            identifier="LARGE"/>
    </entity-set>

    <entity-set entitySetId="BreedEntitySet">
        <entity
            name="@string-array/breed"
            identifier="Golden Retriever"/>
    </entity-set>
</actions>
```

Answer (score 1):

[actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE BII](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) supports a single feature. Your use case cannot be represented with it unless you fast forward to a single feature, and then let your application continue the conversation from that point.

Also, I think you're conflating Conversational Actions Built-in Intents(BIIs) and App Actions BIIs, and your actions.xml includes a valid App Action BII(OPEN_APP_FEATURE) along with invalid BIIs. That being said, stay tuned for new features that will meet your use case.